# Create a new variable base on other variables contain a specific value in r

Tags: r, variables

I have several time serious variables and I want to create two new dummy variables. 
Variable one: if other variables contain a specific value, then variable one equal 1.
Variable two: if other variables contain a specific value continuously, then variable two equal 1.

My data looks like

```
ID score_2011 score_2012 score_2013 score_2014 score_2015
1          12         15         96         96         16
2          12         15         15         15         16
3          12         96         20         15         16
4          12         15         18         15         16
5          12         15         96         15         16
```

I want to get the new variables like the following

```
IF score_2011~2015 contain 96 then with_96=1
IF score_2011~2015 contain continuous 96 then back_to_back_96=1
```

I want the result to look like..

```
  ID    score_2011 score_2012 score_2013  score_2014  score_2015  with_96  back_to_back_96
    1          12         15         96         96         16       1               1
    2          12         15         15         15         16       0               0
    3          12         96         20         15         16       1               0
    4          12         15         18         15         16       0               0
    5          96         15         96         15         16       1               0
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to loop through the rows, find if there are `any` values that are 96 ('x1'), do run-length encoding on each of the rows, check whether there are `any` of the `lengths` for the 'TRUE' values are greater than 1 ('x2') , concatenate both, transpose and assign two new columns to the output.

```
df1[c("with_96", "back_to_back_96")] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN= function(x) {
          x1 <- as.integer(any(x==96))
          rl <- rle(x==96)
          x2 <- any(rl$lengths[rl$values]>1)
          c(x1, x2)}))
df1
#  ID score_2011 score_2012 score_2013 score_2014 score_2015 with_96 back_to_back_96
#1  1         12         15         96         96         16       1               1
#2  2         12         15         15         15         16       0               0
#3  3         12         96         20         15         16       1               0
#4  4         12         15         18         15         16       0               0
#5  5         12         15         96         15         16       1               0
```

---

Or another option is using `rowSums`

```
df1["with_96"] <- +(!!rowSums(df1[-1]==96))
df1["back_to_back_96"] <-  rowSums((df1[-c(1, ncol(df1))]==96)  + 
                 (df1[-c(1,2)]==96)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some fanciness with `data.table` if you are so inclined. Working on a long format, melted dataset might make the logic of some of these comparisons a bit simpler.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
melt(dat, id="ID")[, .(with96=any(value==96), b2b96=any(diff(which(value==96))==1)), by=ID]

#   ID with96 b2b96
#1:  1   TRUE  TRUE
#2:  2  FALSE FALSE
#3:  3   TRUE FALSE
#4:  4  FALSE FALSE
#5:  5   TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks. Because I have other variable in the data frame, how do I use your code to limit to column 2 to 5?